# Entity Framework book for beginners

Tags: entity-framework

I picked up Julia Lerman 1st edition book:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18212/entity-framework-book-1st-edition

I started reading that and it was pretty good, but I'm wondering if there is even a more higher level book for EF?  From what I was reading in the 1st edition it was pretty technical.  I'm looking for a real high level book.  Almost like a precursor to Julia's book (2nd edition).

Are there any out there that this group would recommend?

Comment: What are you wanting to understand?  I have not found a good book that really leverages integrating EF and ASP.net/WCF/WPF.

Comment: I really want to understand why I need EF at the most basic levels.

Answer (score 2):

> "I really want to understand why I need EF at the most basic levels"

Entity Framework just simplifies your day to day data access. Instead of thinking how to create a data access layer or spending time writing raw SQL queries, EF can just do it. Is it the 100% solution for your projects, no, but it will sure get you closer faster than trying to write things by hand.

In response to your questions about books, Lerman's books are probably the best in showing Entity Framework working in a number of different scenarios. The book that Chad referenced is also another good resource. But I'd also recommend taking a look at the ADO.Net Team Blog and read some of their [entries on Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/tags/entity+framework/), along with the [Entity Framework Blog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/efdesign/)and using the [Data Developer Center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/) to get a good understanding of when, how and why to use Entity Framework.

Nice to see that you're diving into Entity Framework and hope it helps you out in your projects.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real "NEED" for entity framework.  However it does simplify the data layer integration with your .net applications.  We used to create classes manually and write our queries for inserts and updates and create methods for them.  Entity framework simplifies this. It manages your classes based on your datastructure.  Not to mention it leverages tools like LINQ to make accessing your data simpler for the developer.  3.5 has a much higher learning curve than 4.0 as well.
I personally use [Pro Entity Framwork 4.0 by Scott Klien](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/159059990X) for reference.  Its fairly consise and provides some good foundation for using EF.  However as I said I have not really seen a good book that discusses leveraging EF and ASP.Net/WinForm etc.  But I have found it pretty easy to figure out once I stared using it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation; specifically the [Entity Framework Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Otherwise, the jump start page for learning EF is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx). It has different ways of starting to learn EF. I might recommend "I want to watch some videos…"